# How to write the custom format to make 3.33 to be displayed as "3.33" but 3 to be displayed as "3"?

Tags: excel, format-string

I am looking for a custom format for numeric values in Excel to display a value with 2 decimal places without padded zeroes. So that if the number is 3.33, it displays "3.33" in the cell, and if the number is 3, it displays "3" in the cell.

I tried "#,###.##", it will force a decimal point for value 3, so it displays as "3.".

Comment: The standard *General* number format does exactly what you're asking. It displays `3.0` as `3`, `3.1` as `3.1`, and `3.33` as `3.33`. It also displays `3.03` properly. Why do you need a custom format when the standard one works exactly as you require? You don't even need to format the cell - just go to cell A1 and type `3.0` and hit Enter. In A2, type `3.33` and hit Enter. In A3, type `3.03` and hit Enter.

Comment: Good point. But actually 2 decimal place is just an example. What if I want it to be 3 decimal places?

Comment: Same applies. Add *Type `3.0334` in cell A4* to the end of my last comment. Just for fun, also try typing `3.03345` into cell A5. Have you just created a blank Excel worksheet and tested what I wrote in my comment? You could have answered that last question yourself by just typing a value with 3 decimal places into the next cell. Try it. Go wild! Try one with 6 decimal places, one with 7, and maybe one with 8.